# POST, isset, and variables

Tags: php, html

I figured out how to fix my problem, but I really need to understand why I had the problem to begin with..

Posting a form, I want to set the variable and display according to whether the variable is set or not. I made a test code since the full page is very long. 
The test code worked fine, but not on the page.

First code that does not work on my page but tests ok is this:

```
<?php
$itype=0;
if (isset($_POST['itype'])) {
$itype=strip_tags($_POST['itype']); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<form action="test.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" method="post"><input class="invisible" type="radio" name="itype" checked="checked" value="Weapon" /><input class="small" type="submit" value="Weapons" /></form>
<?php
if ($itype==0) {
echo $itype;
}
else {
echo $itype;
}
?>
```

It breaks when I add it to my page. The only way to get it to work on the page is to change the preset variable $itype from 0 to 'All'. I need to understand why i have to use a string on the full page but not the test script?

Here is the full page, I apoligize its long but I have no idea which code is relevant. It's too long to paste here so here is the link:
[inventory](https://github.com/AliciaAMT/inventory)

I am teaching myself, never any classroom experience. I really want to understand this even tho it's not a pressing issue for my project. At first I thought 'type' was a banned variable so i changed it to 'itype'. Then I thought it had something to do with being a number vs a string, but that cannot be since it works fine in the short test script. I have searched the manual and this site but cannot find an answer, or at least not an answer I understand.

EDIT
Here is what I think is the most relevant code as I applied it to my page:

```
    <?php
    $itype='All';
    if (isset($_POST['itype'])) {
    $itype=strip_tags($_POST['itype']); 
    }
    if ($itype=='All')
    {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE charname=:charname and keep>0 and itemtype != 'Food' ORDER BY equipable desc, itemtype desc, weapontype, itemlevel desc, itemrarity");
                    $stmt->execute(array(':charname' => $charname));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
    include ('../includes/displayinv.php');
    }
    }
    else
    {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE charname=:charname and keep>0 and itemtype = :type order by weapontype, itemlevel desc, itemrarity");
                    $stmt->execute(array(':charname' => $charname,
                    ':type' => $itype
                    ));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
    include ('../includes/displayinv.php');
    }
    }
    ?>
<form action="inventory.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" method="post"><input class="invisible" type="radio" name="itype" checked="checked" value="Weapon" /><input class="small" type="submit" value="Weapons" /></form>
```

it's an inventory menu. i want to display all the items unless the user selects a button to display inventory by item type, like weapons versus armor. the type is how i query mysql inventory item table to display desired items. 
when i implement the code with 0s instead of 'All' as the preset variable the form breaks down and continues to display all the items, the buttons no longer work to display only the selected items. Here is the code with 0's that stops working:

```
<?php
        $itype=0;
        if (isset($_POST['itype'])) {
        $itype=strip_tags($_POST['itype']); 
        }
        if ($itype==0)
        {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE charname=:charname and keep>0 and itemtype != 'Food' ORDER BY equipable desc, itemtype desc, weapontype, itemlevel desc, itemrarity");
                        $stmt->execute(array(':charname' => $charname));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
        include ('../includes/displayinv.php');
        }
        }
        else
        {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE charname=:charname and keep>0 and itemtype = :type order by weapontype, itemlevel desc, itemrarity");
                        $stmt->execute(array(':charname' => $charname,
                        ':type' => $itype
                        ));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
        include ('../includes/displayinv.php');
        }
        }
        ?>
    <form action="inventory.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" method="post"><input class="invisible" type="radio" name="itype" checked="checked" value="Weapon" /><input class="small" type="submit" value="Weapons" /></form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? The query doesn't work?

Comment: From what I understand you make a query based on this variable. You are selecting something from the db and you are doing it with a where clause on the itemtype column. If you don't have any itemtype with 0 value then nothing will show up, right?

Comment: it's an inventory menu. i want to display all the items unless the user selects a button to display inventory by item type, like weapons versus armor. the type is how i query mysql inventory item table to display desired items.

Comment: when i implement the code, the buttons no longer work to display only the selected items

Comment: btw, I have only implemented the very first collapsible under the first button. The rest of the page is not finished, but should not interfere with the above code and it works fine when I change the 0's to strings

Comment: why use radio buttons, where it is already checked? you can't deselect it?

Comment: Its not meant to be deselected and its hidden. Honestly I wrote that part about 10 years ago and i don't remember why.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare an string with a number, php will cast string to number and compare.
Change this code to:

```
<?php
    $itype="";// change it to empty
    if (isset($_POST['itype'])) {
        $itype=strip_tags($_POST['itype']); 
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <form action="test.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" method="post"><input class="invisible" type="radio" name="itype" checked="checked" value="Weapon" /><input class="small" type="submit" value="Weapons" /></form>
<?php
    if ($itype==""// change it to empty) {
    echo $itype;
}
else {
    echo $itype;
}
?>
```

Comment: I still don't understand because that test code actually works fine before you changed it to a string. It just stops working when I apply it to the full page. Does the breakdown happen elsewhere maybe? mysql query?  I wouldn't think so however because it throws no errors and still displays all the items in the inventory as if the itype variable was still 0 or else nothing would be displayed or an error would throw